# Apps missing after sd card unmount

Tags: applications, sd-card, installation, app2sd

The core issue is in the title: the apps that were installed in the SD card seem to be not installed at all after I unmounted the SD card.

As additional information, these are the steps preceding the moment I have noticed this problem:

- installed some apps (so, it's not an app-specific problem)
- moved many of them to the SD card using [App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apptosd.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hcHB0b3NkLmxpdGUiXQ..) - apps working properly
- unmounted the SD card and detached from the phone (which is turned on)
- no data were written on the sd card (only read operations)
- put SD back in the phone (the *same* SD card)

At this point, I was, and currently am, not able to launch the applications previously moved in the SD card. The links are available on my home screen, but after tapping them I get an error message saying "error launching application".

They are not available in the app menu, neither are marked as "installed" in the play store.

Fortunately, the applications' data are still there, and installing some of the apps again they appeared the same as the last time I used them.

So, the question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to recover the apps, or do I have to manually reinstall them?
2. Is this a potential bug of App2SD?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the phone?

Comment: I did it several time (the phone has a strange behavior     since I reported the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a case of a vital hidden folder that you're missing - when apps are moved to the SD-Card, a hidden folder called `.android_secure` is created which is where the apps are stored in!

This is a common mistake to make, when replacing a SD-Card for a bigger one, so the moral is to ensure, when transferring to a bigger SD-Card, do not forget the hidden directories including `.android_secure`. Upon restart after inserting the bigger SD-Card, Android will re-scan the card and proceed to look in that specific hidden folder, for any apps that are moved to external storage and loads/caches the shortcuts for those respective apps.

Comment: That folder is called `.android_secure` :) Further your answer implies the OP switched cards -- the question doesn't indicate that: *put SD **back** in the phone* rather implies it was the same card. Apart from that: Good point!

Comment: @Izzy Gosh thanks for the heads up... will edit it accordingly! ;)

Comment: NP -- but you're still assuming the OP copied contents to a new card, which is not what the Q says (well, but it also doesn't deny it, so I'll give you a +1 nevertheless :)

Comment: Maybe I am in denial too... methinks the OP should clarify if that was the case? :)

Comment: @Izzy is right: I didn't change the SD card: it is the same. No data were written or changed while it was off the phone.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin - Thanks for the clarification :) Ok... something is not quite right.. now forgive my ignorance, but when a card is unmounted, it does not mean to actually pull it out - am thinking aloud - ejected safely, unless you uncovered a bug with Apps2SD in that it failed to recognize the unmount and did not eject it.... just a thought...

Comment: ...which should mean the same problem would occur when mounting the card via USB to a computer, wouldn't it? What would happen then? Is it unmounted locally or, as I read lately, simply gets its permissions reset to 000? Would `/sdcard/.android_secure` become unavailable in both cases (is it even handed to the computer this way?) But I guess that goes to far here :)

Comment: @Izzy, With windows, there's a very good reason for safe eject with regards to cards, the buffers holding the filesystem on card has to be flushed in a safe manner prior to ejecting, maybe the OP pulled it out with-out ejecting safely and that might have scrambled the dot directories (hidden directories)????

Comment: As a rule I generally un-mount the sdcard, power off the phone and can then remove it, I would not be 100% confident in pulling it out (despite being unmounted) when the phone is still on....

Comment: True about that -- but why should it have damaged only the hidden directories then (even more as the OP was unlikely to touch anythin in there)? Also, quoting: *no data were written on the sd card (only read operations)* So it *shouldn't* have mattered (but you're right: Who knows?)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but we might have different phones. For me, the reason why I never see my apps moved by app2ds is because my sd card is partitioned so that app2sd would be able to see only that part of the card, and my computer cannot see the partitioned part. Whenever I unmount my sd card to switch it out with one I have music on, I just have to restart the whole phone afterwards is all.